# What does this refer to in an onfilterchange attribute?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've taken code from the [MSDN page on Matrix Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx) and modified it slightly.  The functions all expect an input variable `oObj` which gets passed in originally from the `onfilterchange`:

```
<DIV ID="oDiv" STYLE="position:absolute;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand')"
    onfilterchange="fnSpin(this)" >
```

What I'm now trying to do is send arbitrary values to the `setRotation` function using the `onclick` event of a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="var theDiv = document.getElementById('oDiv'); setRotation(theDiv,45)" value="Set">
```

Unfortunately when I click the button I get an Error: Object expected.  I've obviously misunderstood what exactly `this` refers to in the `onfilterchange` - I thought it would be the HTML Element with ID oDiv.  As far as I can tell [filters should exist on the DIV element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537452%28VS.85%29.aspx).  I remember recently reading an excellent description of what `this` refers to in different situations in [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/), but I don't have access to the print version right now, and searching the Safari edition for "this" hasn't been very productive.

Things I've tried (mostly in the hope that it's an obscure IE bug):

- Having `document.getElementById('oDiv')` as the first argument to `setRotation`
- Using `document.all` instead of `getElementById`
- Using different properties such as `styles`

[Complete code is online here](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/ietest.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have a typo:

Yours:

```
<input type="button" onclick="var theDiv = document.getElementById('oDiv'); setRotation(theDiv,45)" value="Set">
```

Websites:

```
<input type="button" onclick="var theDiv = document.getElementById('oDiv').style; setRotation(theDiv,45)" value="Set">
```

theDiv seems to refer to the **style** property of the actual div itself.

Comment: Actually I just realised I have a much worse typo than that - I have setRotation and not fnSetRotation.  I'm a muppet!